# How to make Change event and data validation work when copying data in multiple cells in a column(M) at a time using Excel Macro

Tags: excel, vba

I am able to run the validation and change event trigger to work on one cell(reference here is M6). When the user select "Valid" or "Not Valid" from the dropdown list it should populate name of the user and date in adjacent columns(N6,O6), this is working fine if I am selecting the option from drop down or copying the value one cell at a time.

Somehow the macro does not work when I copy the value in multiple cells(M8:M10) at a time, nor it is working when using the autofill option to populate records in the cells of that column. Also tried to insert a non-valid data "adsadasdad
" in Cell M8, the validation worked, but when inserting non-valid data in multiple cells, validation is not working.

Please find the macro code

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Set MainWB = ThisWorkbook
    LastRow = MainWB.Worksheets("LDVC_data").Cells(MainWB.Worksheets("LDVC_data").Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 2 To LastRow

    If Target.Address = Range("M" & i).Address Then
    If Range("M" & i) = "Valid" Or Range("M" & i) = "Not Valid" Then

      ActiveSheet.Range("N" & i).Value = (Environ$("Username"))
       ActiveSheet.Range("O" & i).Value = Now
      ElseIf (Range("M" & i) = "[enter image description here][1]") Then
       ActiveSheet.Range("N" & i).Clear
       ActiveSheet.Range("O" & i).Clear
      Else[enter image description here][1]
      MsgBox ("Kindly enter valid value")
      Range("M" & i) = ""
    End If
   End If
  Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to capture the change and perform data validation in multiple cells.
Did following changes to the code.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim LastRow As Long
Set MainWB = ThisWorkbook
Dim myRange As Range
Set myRange = Target
LastRow = MainWB.Worksheets("LDVC_data").Cells(MainWB.Worksheets("LDVC_data").Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
For Each targetCell In Target
For i = 2 To LastRow
    If targetCell.Address = Range("M" & i).Address Then
        If Range("M" & i) = "Valid" Or Range("M" & i) = "Not Valid" Then
            ActiveSheet.Range("N" & i).Value = (Environ$("Username"))
            ActiveSheet.Range("O" & i).Value = Now
        ElseIf (Range("M" & i) = "") Then
            ActiveSheet.Range("N" & i).Clear
            ActiveSheet.Range("O" & i).Clear
        Else
            MsgBox ("Kindly enter valid value")
            Range("M" & i) = ""
        End If
    End If
Next i
Next targetCell
End Sub
```